# PHP: Notice Undefined index even using isset

Tags: php, function, isset

i'm getting this even using 'isset':

```
Notice: Undefined index
```

it's giving the error at:

```
returnifisset($_COOKIE["miceusername"], ' value="', '"');
```

even though i am checking if the cookie isset or not. The function is:

```
function returnifisset($variable, $first = '', $last = ''){
    if(isset($variable) and !empty($variable)){ return $first.$variable.$last; }
}
```

how i should modify this function to make it work and not give that error!

Comment: You are not using isset until you are inside the function.  PHP looks at the cookie and the index before the variable is processed by the function.  That is where your error is coming from.

Comment: You would need to do `printifisset(isset($COOKIE["miceusername"], ' value="', '"');)` which totally defeats the purpose of using the function at all.  My suggestion is to skip the function altogether as it is rather unnecessary and the savings you get from typing it in full are minimal if any at all.

Comment: @Ameer Replace the function with code. Instead of calling `returnifisset` substitute the code within the function. Also, just to make sure you know: Calling return from `returnifisset` would not return a value for the calling context. You would have to use `return returnifsset('...','...','...');` if you wanted that.

Comment: @Jrod it works that way but why? why this way? why not with a function?

Comment: It's because php looks at the variable you are passing to the function before executing the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually accessing the variable by passing it with your function, before the isset is ever called. You can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You use different function names printifisset and returnifisset.
Also you can use only !empty() statement