# PHP - Unidentified index in error log even though using isset to check for session variable

Tags: php, session-variables, middleware, slim

I am running the following check in PHP (in a Slim middleware) to make sure that a certain session variable exists:

```
public function __invoke($request, $response, $next) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])) { // this is line 17
      // do something
    }

    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;

}
```

However, my error log is swamped with the following:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: errors in /our/path/app/Middleware/ValidationErrorsMiddleware.php on line 17
```

What can I do to have this not show as an error?

I found a solution here: [PHP: Notice Undefined index even using isset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096914/php-notice-undefined-index-even-using-isset) but my case is different as I'm not accessing the variable prior to the check.

Comment: What is on line 17?

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: My PHP version is 7.1

Comment: Seems very odd if that's the case, if you comment out the `if(isset(..))` does it still throw the notice? Additionally, are the notices logged in the file recent? Could they be lingering from when your script was different?

Comment: Notices come every day and not just for this script but for another one with a similar case. This is the latest log.

Comment: `isset()` should never get that warning. Are you certain that this is the line where it's happening?

Comment: Yes and it happens on more than one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_key_exists instead of isset

```
if(array_key_exists('errors', $_SESSION)) {
 //Do something
}
```

Here you can find the docs:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I'm not getting more of those notices.